# How to obtain additional info from the 'Win32_ProcessStopTrace' class through WMI?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, wmi

### Scenario

Foe hobbie or practice I'm developing a (very)simple process monitor that exposes two events to suscribe to process starts and process stops trough two `ManagementEventWatcher` objects.

With a `ManagementEventWatcher` object using queries to `Win32_ProcessStartTrace` and `Win32_ProcessStopTrace` classes I suscribe to process starts and stops discoveries then I raise the corresponding `EventArrivedEventHandler` event to expose the info of the process that has started or stopped, in an event-oriented way.

---

### Problem

The problem is that I would like to obtain the additional (basic) info like the executable path and PID of the process that has been started or stopped, but the `Win32_ProcessStartTrace` and `Win32_ProcessStopTrace` classes does not expose that info/property.

- **[Win32_ProcessStopTrace - MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/es-ar/aa394376)**
- **[Win32_ProcessStartTrace - MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/es-ar/aa394374)**

On the other hand, they exposes a `ProcessName` property which in the docs says this:

> You can use this name to get the instance of Win32_Process for the
>   same process.

- **[Win32_Process - MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-ar/aa394372)**

However, how MSDN expects that I could do that efficiently taking into account that various processes with the same filename could be running at same time?.

If the only useful info that those classes provides me are a process name and a parent PID then in terms of efficiency what the hell MSDN expects I could do to match the target process I want to get additional info doing an WMI query to `Win32_Process` class when it can exists various processes with the same name and created by the same process?, nothing, so... I'm very stuck at this point.

I think that is necessary something more consistent to perform an efficient `Win32_Process` query, like for example a **PID** of the process (not a Parent PID).

---

### Question

In C# or VB.Net, and in terms of efficiency (because to avoid what I explained above), what I could do to obtain additional info of the right process after the `EventArrivedEventHandler` has arrived?.

My expectations are to obtain some unique identifier like a PID, then I can perform a WMI query to `Win32_Process` class to obtain all the additional info I want, not only a process name and parent PID.

---

### Source-code

This is the relevant part of the code:

```
Public Class ProcessWatcher : Implements IDisposable

    Private WithEvents processStartWatcher As ManagementEventWatcher
    Private WithEvents processStopWatcher As ManagementEventWatcher

    ''' <summary>
    ''' Occurs when a process starts (run).
    ''' </summary>
    Public Event ProcessStarted As EventArrivedEventHandler

    ''' <summary>
    ''' Occurs when a process stops (exit).
    ''' </summary>
    Public Event ProcessStopped As EventArrivedEventHandler

    Public Sub New()
        Me.processStartWatcher = New ManagementEventWatcher(New WqlEventQuery("SELECT * FROM Win32_ProcessStartTrace"))
        Me.processStopWatcher = New ManagementEventWatcher(New WqlEventQuery("SELECT * FROM Win32_ProcessStopTrace"))
    End Sub

    ''' <summary>
    ''' Start monitoring for process starts and stops.
    ''' </summary>
    <DebuggerStepThrough>
    Public Sub Start()
        Me.processStartWatcher.Start()
        Me.processStopWatcher.Start()
    End Sub

    ''' <summary>
    ''' Stop monitoring for process starts and stops.
    ''' </summary>
    <DebuggerStepThrough>
    Public Sub [Stop]()

        Me.processStartWatcher.Stop()
        Me.processStopWatcher.Stop()

    End Sub

    Protected Overridable Sub RaiseProcessStartedEvent(ByVal e As EventArrivedEventArgs)
        RaiseEvent ProcessStarted(Me, e)
    End Sub

    Protected Overridable Sub RaiseProcessStoppedEvent(ByVal e As EventArrivedEventArgs)
        RaiseEvent ProcessStopped(Me, e)
    End Sub

    Private Sub ProcessStartWatcher_EventArrived(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArrivedEventArgs) _
    Handles processStartWatcher.EventArrived

        If (Me.ProcessStartedEvent IsNot Nothing) Then
            Me.RaiseProcessStartedEvent(e)
        End If

    End Sub

    Private Sub ProcessStopWatcher_EventArrived(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArrivedEventArgs) _
    Handles processStopWatcher.EventArrived

        If (Me.ProcessStoppedEvent IsNot Nothing) Then
            Me.RaiseProcessStoppedEvent(e)
        End If

    End Sub

End Class
```

And an usage example:

```
Imports System.Management

Public Class Form1 : Inherits Form

    Private WithEvents processWatcher As New ProcessWatcher

    Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) _
    Handles MyBase.Load

        Me.processWatcher.Start()

    End Sub

    Private Sub ProcessWatcher_ProcessStarted(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArrivedEventArgs) _
    Handles processWatcher.ProcessStarted

        Console.WriteLine(String.Format("Process started | Name: {0}", e.NewEvent.Properties("ProcessName").Value))
        Console.WriteLine(String.Format("Process started | PPid: {0}", e.NewEvent.SystemProperties("ParentProcessID").Value))

    End Sub

    Private Sub Form1_FormClosing(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As FormClosingEventArgs) _
    Handles MyBase.FormClosing

        Me.processWatcher.Stop()

    End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: Wouldnt the SessionID, ProcessName and ParentProcessID together identify the process?

Comment: @Plutonix Thanks for comment. It is a rhetorical question? because really I'm not sure about the answer, I've just explained my logic, Think that if a process in the same session can own two processes with the same name, then that could answer the question you've made?. Or maybe I have a wrong idea of those values together?. Thanks again!.

Comment: Have you tried to get the 'ProcessID' property? My WMIEXplorer tool reports this property exists on both events (maybe derives from a base class)

Comment: @Simon Mourier thanks for comment, You've reason!. Before asking the question I tried to retrieve some other properties of the **Win32_Process** class like **ExecutablePath** but didn't worked and thats why I asked the question, but now I tried with **ProcessId** and it works. thanks a lot, feel free to publish an answer to mark it as accepted!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although the documentation does not talk about it, there is indeed a 'ProcessID' property on Win32_ProcessStopTrace and Win32_ProcessStartTrace as both classes derive from Win32_ProcessTrace which has it. You can check this using a tool such as [WMIExplorer](https://wmie.codeplex.com/):

[image]